# Neo4J opens world-available IPv6 port by default. Why? Possible to disable?

Tags: neo4j

On a default Ubuntu 14.04 installation, the Neo4J service (installed from the apt repo) opens up four ports. Three are bound to localhost (http, https, shell). But another, ephemeral IPv6 port is bound to ::. What is this port used for? How can I disable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you the exact reason but the port opened up is tied to the remote shell feature, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell.html. Remote shell is using RMI under the hoods .

You can force Neo4j to not open that port by disabling remote shell (which is enabled by default, but limited to localhost). In `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.properties` set

```
remote_shell_enabled=false
```

and restart Neo4j.